# Explain belongsTo in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, belongs-to

From the [Grails belongsTo](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html) documentation, what is the use of

```
   class Book {
    static belongsTo = Author
}
```

What is the impact of cascading operations on Book, when CRUD operations performed on Author?

EDIT:

Thanks for your responses, may be i didn't specify my question correctly. I would like to know the difference between

```
 static belongsTo [author:Author]
```

vs

```
 static belongsTo = Author
```

Comment: Regarding your edit, the two are not any different (and actually, the first should be `static belongsTo = [ author: Author ]`). They will have the same effect. The first form just lets you specify the name of the property.

Answer (score 11):

`belongsTo` is helpful if you need a reference back to the owning object. In this case it is likely that an `Author` has many `Book`s. But maybe you're using a book object and want to mention that book instance's `Author`. That is a good way to get it.

As far as CRUD goes, deleting or updating the book will not do anything to the `Author`, but deleting the `Author` will delete the `Book`. If you don't add `belongsTo` then there will be no cascading saves/updates/deletes, you will have to do it manually.

**Example:**

```
def a = new Author(name: 'J.K. Rawling')
a.addToBooks(new Book(title: 'Harry Potter 1'))
a.addToBooks(new Book(title: 'Harry Potter 2'))
a.save()   // Saves author and book instances

a.delete() // Author and both books are deleted
```

**Edit:**

The OP updated their question, and I'm honestly not sure what the answer would be. Hopefully Burt Beckwith will show up soon! Good question, OP.

Comment: It should be `J. K. Rowling` :))

Answer (score 1):

Both ways offer cascading effects in the same way. Their only difference is that in the former case you'll have  a reference to author in `Book` object whereas you don't in the latter. That is:

You can say `Book b = new Book(); b.author` in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Grantmc:

belongsTo practically marks an embedded kind of relation between the two, this is why all operations are cascaded automatically when this is used.

Without belongsTo you need to manually define cascades (if you want anycascades at al for your relatoinship)

Comment: what are cascades in this case? only for deleting say books when you delete an author? If you never delete, does BelongsTo help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems confusing and extra effort to me it was since I can achieve same result on the relationship by just simply using one `hasMany` and ignore `belongsTo`, but you need to make let say `Author` class variable in `Book` Domain/Class

```
class Author {
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}

class Book {
    Author author  //can have only one Instance to be saved at a time
}
```

But the reason you use `belongsTo` is it is enforcing the relationship to follow the path from `Author` to `Book` when inserting data, keeping a perfect way of governing the relationship using `belongsTo`. If you don't specify it as class variable or use `belongsto` Grails is not going to understand the two way relationship at all.

Comment: Personally, I still dont see the difference between: class Book {Author author} and class Book { static belongsTo = Author}.  Both are specifying that a book has an author (hence must belong to by definition).  I always use the former, I have never used belogsTo, and havent noticed any issues (I never delete data, only mark as deleted)

Answer (score 0):

As the [doc says](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html), it is the same to do belongsTo = [author:Author] than belongsTo = Autor, both will create a property called author referencing the "father" object.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

```
1. static belongsTo [author:Author]
2. static belongsTo = Author
```

In the first there would be a backreference to Author but not in the second case with corresponding cascading implications.