# What is the difference between mappedBy and belongsTo for m-m relationships?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

What is the difference between mappedBy and belongsTo for m-m relationships in Grails? How can the two be used in a same Domain?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 3 with 1 that has two formats:

There is belongsTo:
`belongsTo=[something:Something]` and `belongsTo=Something` or  `belongsTo=[Something,Another]`

There is `Something something`

and finally  `hasOne=[something:Something]`

When you declare `Something something`  this actually creates a table cell called something_id

When you declare `belongsTo=[something:Something]`  `something_id` isn't created and I think if I understand correctly that relationship is now managed by hibernate.

Points of reference [Explain belongsTo in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593218/explain-belongsto-in-grails) and [Grails hasOne vs. belongsTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166149/grails-hasone-vs-belongsto)

So in short one you manage the relationship through `db` and other is managed by hibernate.

How can the two be used in the same domain ?

Why would you need both if they are both pointing to the same parent ?

You can use either method for any relationship the belongsTo is a hibernate control mechanism telling it what / which way the relationship is so therefore the Parent must have `Child child` mapping

Where as `Something something` or `Parent parent` really has none of the above requirements.  Hope it is making sense